# How can I use one column as multi foreign key in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-9

I want to use one column as a foreign key for two different tables. How can I do that on Laravel?

```
Schema::create('order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->float('price');
    $table->string('stock_keeping_unity');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->foreign('order_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreign('order_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('cart_controls')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
   
    $table->foreign('product_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('products')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

**Error**

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'order_details_order_id_foreign'")

Comment: do you get  an error

Comment: I don't know yet what you would want to achieve but, I don't think It's possible with relational databases

Comment: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'order_details_order_id_foreign'") I am getting this error. I tought Composite Key is not supporting by eloquent.

Comment: I am trying to do relational model. but I didnt understand.

Answer (score 0):

laravel gives teh same name because you have both times the same names for all columns, simple rename the second foreign key

```
    $table->foreign('order_id','order_details_order_id_foreign_cart')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('cart_controls')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```